Primality testing for 3-number set
Suppose we know that exactly one of the three integers $2^{1000} + 277,~ 2^{1000} + 291$ and
$2^{1000} + 297$ is prime.  How can we find which one is prime?  None of these integers has a small prime factor $(<10^8)$.

On my computer, Maple takes about $1/10$ second to test all three for primality.    It uses one  strong pseudoprimality test and one Lucas test.

Wolfram alpha works too, and it says $1.8733993×10^{\color{red}7}$ divides $2^{1000}+277$

The idea was to solve the problem using the information given, without sophisticated software using fast prime-testing algorithms.  Of course using a computer is allowed, just not functions like Mathematica's PrimeQ[].
